# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, WSGIRequest found

Tags: python, django, unicode, model, view

TypeError at /nvbn/home.html
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, WSGIRequest found
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/nvbn/home.html
Django Version: 1.7.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, WSGIRequest found
Exception Location: C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\eggs.py in load_template_source, line 26
Python Executable:  C:\Anaconda\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:
['c:\DjangoProjects\quickclaim',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-11.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django_ajax_search-1.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\Anaconda\python27.zip',
 'C:\Anaconda\DLLs',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\plat-win',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk',
 'C:\Anaconda',
 'c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\runipy-0.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.2.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Thu, 22 Jan 2015 15:07:25 -0500

**Here is my model:**

```
class Claim(models.Model):
def __str__(self):              
    return self.claim_id
policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy);
claim_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True);
loss_dt = models.DateTimeField();
loss_location = models.CharField(max_length=100);
clam_stat = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='open');
cas_aia_cds_1_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50);
cas_aia_cds_3_4 = models.CharField(max_length=50);
reported_dt = models.DateTimeField();
loss_desc = models.TextField();
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-loss_dt','reported_dt']
```

**In views.py:**

```
  def home(request):
try:
    claims = m.Claim.objects.all()
    claims_list = []

    for c in claims:
        claims_list.append(c.loss_desc)

    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'claim_list': claims_list
    })
    return render_to_response(request, 'home.html', context_instance=context)
except m.Claim.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

**What I am trying to do is to send a list of Claim Objects to template.**
Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render_to_response` doesn't take `request` as an argument.

Remove it and leave the rest as is.